# limit movement of jquery ui draggable outside frame borders

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jquery ui draggable in order to make a fieldset draggable by user, the whole page is loaded inside an iframe. **the problem is that I can drag the fieldset outside the iframe borders, how I can stop that?**

```
<iframe src='test.html'></iframe>
```

test.html

```
    <html>
<script>
$(".draggable").draggable();
</script>
<fieldset id='draggable'>testing</fieldset>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your selectors: I think you're mixing `classes` for `IDs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the UI `containment` option

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: "parent";
});
```